# I need a working android rosjava eclipse project

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community!

Does anybody have a working android rosjava project for eclipse? Preferably Android API Level 8. The rosjava android tutorials (https://code.google.com/p/rosjava.android/) seem to be old, because they cannot be used without making changes (like assigning a node name, or setting "java.net.preferIPv6Addresses" to false - at least I had to do those changes to be able to run the tutorials).

But even after adapting the rosjava android tutorials, they don't work. ROS communication between android and roscore (running on a separate machine) doesn't work.

So I was asking whether someone could give me a working up-to-date rosjava android project.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12589/i-need-a-working-android-rosjava-eclipse-project/) by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just updated the android_tutorial_pubsub to use all of the latest APIs. I suggest basing your Android projects on that.

I apologize for the state of the examples/tutorials currently as I have not had time to refresh them.

That being said, do understand that working at head can lead to headaches (that was a pun, get it?) since things change rapidly.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on 2012-01-30**:
I realized my android version wasn't compatible with the tutorials. My adaptations were correct, but thank you for updating the tutorials!